# How can I save multiple sequential plots generated by one function in R?

Tags: r, plot

Some functions can draw a plot  for each of multiple data. So  it  looks like a movie with many plots shown one after another very quickly. Examples of such functions including `plot` and `gelman.plot` of the output returned by `BRugsFit()`, when there are many parameters and each plot for each parameter.

Because it flashes too fast, I want to examine each plot carefully before looking at the next plot. So I would like to save the plots into files, (if not possible, I would hope to slow down the flashing or at least have some control).

1. To save the plots,  I try to put them into a single figure, but I
   haven't figured out how to do that successfully (note that I run R in bash terminal, not using any IDE such as RStudio):

   ```
   > pdf('gelman.pdf')
   > par(mfrow=c(10,10)); gelman.plot(output,auto.layout=F,autoburnin=F)
   Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
   > dev.off()
   null device 
             1 
   > 
   > pdf('tracedensity.pdf')
   > par(mfrow=c(10,14)); plot(output,auto.layout=F)
   Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
   > dev.off()
   null device 
             1
   ```
2. Alternatively, I wonder if I can save each plot into a different pdf
   file? Or group a smaller number of plots into several files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the `par` - which means you're trying to fit all the graphs on one page, but the error about figure margins means R isn't able to fit them on the same page so is producing no output.  The remaining code  will produce a multi-page pdf, one chart per page.

Alternatively, if you must have them on the same page, then use a larger page `pdf('gelman.pdf', height=70, width=70)` should do it.