# Save multiple plots from function in R

Tags: r, plot, raster

I am using the R package intensity.analysis and the function CIA of the package. Once I execute the function, I get multiple plots. However, one is overlapping on the other and I can only see and save the last one.

Probably it is a simple question, but I have not found any answer googling it, as many people refer to displaying several plots at the same time. What I want is being able to see all the graphs that the function generates automatically and save them.

Could you provide me any help?
I will leave you the code below.

Edit: actually I have the same question that this user posted before ([How can I save multiple sequential plots generated by one function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554287/how-can-i-save-multiple-sequential-plots-generated-by-one-function-in-r)). However, I have not the code of the function, so I cannot even try to play with it and avoid the parameter that the answer to that question gives as the solution.

```
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(sabre)
library(intensity.analysis)

C05 <- raster("C05.rst")
C11 <- raster("C11.rst")
C18 <- raster("C18.rst")

raster.layers <- list(C05, C11, C18)
time.points <- c("2005","2011","2018")
categories <- c("Agricultural areas", "Vegetation areas", "Urban fabric", "Industrial and commercial areas", "Mineral extraction sites", "Dump sites", "Road and rail networks", "Port areas", "Airports", "Artificial green urban areas", "Open spaces with little or no vegetation", "Water bodies", "Background")

crosstab.output <- crosstabulation <- multicrosstab(raster.layers, time.points, categories)

CIA.output <- CIA(crosstabulation, time.points, categories)
filename <- file.path(normalizePath(tempdir(), winslash = "/"), "CIA.csv")
CIA2csv(CIA.output, time.points, categories, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set your graphical parameters with the par() function

```
par(mfrow= c(2,2))
```

the mfrow argument takes a vector of dim 2 to create a "raster" of plot's

so

```
plot(x)
plot(x)
plot(x)
plot(x)
```

will give you this:

like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! :)

However, it does not work. Once I execute the function it gives me at least 5 different plots in a sequence, and it does not matter if I execute the function you have told me first, because it gives me only one per one